# grails dbconsole hasMany links

Tags: grails-domain-class

I am using the H2 hibernate database - where in the database can I access these hasMany links via dbconsole and is it possible to directly delete these links to tidy up some old data?

Comment: Usually, hasMany relationships are created in an additional table (exemple: a user with many tasks will create a new table, probably named user_tasks).

Comment: Abincepto - I thought that would be the case but unable to find one. Also having recycled the app the rogue links seem to have disappeared. Going forward I believe I need to include a removeFrom to tidy up the link in the parent as i am deleting the child. I am having another problem passing Ids to actions as strings instead of expected Longs. I will send a separate post if I cannot resolve.